# Excel: My target cells aren't keeping their borders after Paste...Unless I manually drew (clicked on) each border

Tags: microsoft-excel, border

So this one is rather weird.

Say I am copying the value from Cell A into Cells B & C:

- Cell A (my Copied cell) doesn't have any border formatting.
- Cell B has a border that I drew by dragging out the border area with
  the pencil tool.
- Cell C has a border that I manually clicked on each side to create.

When I paste from A to B, I lose my borders.  When I paste from A to C, I keep them.  If I manually draw over borders I'd already have, the new borders aren't erased when their cell is pasted over.

It's almost like there's a difference in the borders I draw over an area than the ones I draw manually.

What's going on here?

Comment: I tried three different cases (a pencil-drawn border, a border applied by the menu one side at a time, and a border applied by the "outline" menu option.  I got different result from yours.  Pasting into *either* menu applied border erased the border as I assumed it would.  Pasting into the pencil-drawn border, I lost my bottom and right borders.  The top and left borders remained because they ended up being interpreted as the bottom border of the cell above and the right border of the cell to the left.  But still, essentially the opposite of your observation.  (up-to-date O365 v2208 here)

Comment: @Max Ah, so if I understand correctly, borders are a property of a specific cell, not a property of the points between the cells.  Formatting a cell, or dragging the border box around one, seems to only add the border to the internal cells; clicking on a border seems to draw it for both cells adjacent to that border.  That would explain why my manually-drawn borders aren't disappearing when I paste into those cells.  Thank you!

Comment: Correct!  Borders are an attribute of each cell.  The “wall” between two adjacent cells is not its own object that has its own attributes.  In all MS Office products, the program has to decide how to arbitrate conflicts.  If cell A1 has a black outline border and A2 has an orange outline border, Excel, Word, or PowerPoint have to decide which of the two colors wins the tie, as only one of the two colors will be presented.  If I put an outline around A2, C2, B1, and B3, it will make it appear that B2 is outlined, but technically, it actually isn’t.